# Putting JSON data into a List

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have my JSON data coming correctly from my server, I just want to put it into the following array but I'm not sure the JSON data is correctly being inserted into the ArrayList.

Here is the array

```
private List<ShopInfo> createList(int size)  {
    List<ShopInfo> result = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        ShopInfo ci = new ShopInfo();
        ci.name =    TAG_NAME+i;
        ci.address = TAG_ADDRESS+i;
        result.add(ci);
    }
    return result;
}
```

My json

```
{"success":1,"shops":[{"name":"Test_Shop","address":"1 Big Road Dublin"}
```

The file

```
public class OrderCoffee extends Activity {

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> shopList;
private static String url_all_products = "xxxxxxxxxx/ordercoffee.php";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray shops = null;


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SHOPS = "shops";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";


//get a list of participating coffee shops in the locality that are using the app
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_coffee);
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    shopList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ShopAdapter ca = new ShopAdapter(createList(3));
    recList.setAdapter(ca);

}


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array
                shops = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOPS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < shops.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = shops.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    shopList.add(map);


                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private List<ShopInfo> createList(int size)  {
    List<ShopInfo> result = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        ShopInfo ci = new ShopInfo();
        ci.name =    TAG_NAME+i;
        ci.address = TAG_ADDRESS+i;
        result.add(ci);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

ShopAdapter

```
  package com.example.strobe.coffeetime;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by root on 10/04/15.
 */
public class ShopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopAdapter.ShopViewHolder> {

    private List<ShopInfo> shopList;

    public ShopAdapter(List<ShopInfo> shopList) {
        this.shopList = shopList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShopViewHolder shopViewHolder, int i) {
        ShopInfo ci = shopList.get(i);
        shopViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
        shopViewHolder.vAddress.setText(ci.address);

    }

    @Override
    public ShopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new ShopViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class ShopViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView vName;
        protected TextView vAddress;


        public ShopViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            vAddress = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.address);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't seem to be going into the array properly for me"*?

Comment: I'm not sure that the way I'm putting the JSON data into List<ShopInfo> result = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>(); is correct, I wasn't sure how to phrase the question, rephrased.

Comment: can you add this method to your LoadAllProducts asyncTask and print your array: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {Log.d("shopList", shopList.toString());}

Comment: D/shopList﹕ [{name=Test_Shop, address=1 Big Road Dublin}, {name=Test_shop2, address=1 Big Road Dublin}, {name=Test_shop3, address=1 Big Road Dublin}, {name=Test_shop4, address=1 Big Road Dublin}]

Comment: That was the output of the   {Log.d("shopList", shopList.toString());}

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes I just need to put this into the array so I can display it.

Comment: Checkout my answer below I explain why you are getting that result from your createList(int size) method.

Comment: You need to update your recyclerView in the onPostExecute method

Comment: How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm assuming when you say into the array you are referring to the shopList array. The array is ready when onPostExecute is called

Comment: can you post the code for your ShopAdapter

Comment: Sure, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your onCreate to this

```
private RecyclerView recList;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_coffee);
    recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    shopList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}
```

And then in onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    List<ShopInfo> list = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < shopList.size(); i++) {
        ShopInfo ci = new ShopInfo();
        HashMap<String, String> map = shopList.get(i)
        ci.name =    map.get(TAG_NAME);
        ci.address = map.get(TAG_ADDRESS);
        list.add(ci);
    }

    ShopAdapter ca = new ShopAdapter(list);
    recList.setAdapter(ca);
}
```

If you are not using shopList for anything else you can remove it and move the code for creating the list you pass to the adapter to doInBackground

Comment: edited with your suggestions, I got "E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout" http://pastebin.com/Rua0N9LG

Comment: This shows up because the recyclerview is laid out before you get the data. It should work once you set the adapter.

Comment: How do I set the adapter? Sorry it's late here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74979/discussion-between-l-l-and-strobes).

Answer (score 5):

In this line of code :

```
ShopAdapter ca = new ShopAdapter(createList(3));
```

You are calling the `createList(int size)` method which returns an ArrayList with three objects with dummy **ShopInfo** Objects as it's elements.

In the **AsyncTask** You are filling the **shopList** ArrayList but you are never actually using the shopList for anything.

An easier way to parse **JSON** is with the Google's **Gson** library for parsing **JSON**.

Im guessing this is your **ShopInfo** class:

```
public class ShopInfo {
    String name;
    String address;

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public void setAddress(String a){
        address = a;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
}
```

Create a new class like the one below:

```
import java.util.List;
public class ShopInfoList{
     List<ShopInfo> shops;
}
```

Inside your AsyncTask's doInBackground method write the code below:

```
try 
{
    HttpURLConnection connection =  (HttpURLConnection)new URL(YOUR_URL_WITH_JSON).openConnection();
    try 
    {
        InputStream instream =connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        ShopInfoList shopList = new Gson().fromJson(breader, ShopInfoList.class);

        breader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.e("Exception parsing JSON", e);
    }
    finally 
    {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    Log.e("Exception parsing JSON", e);
}
```

But you still have to update your **ShopAdapter** to show them on the List(RecycleView) you can do that in the onPostExecute() method of the **AsyncTask** .

You can check this URL for more details explanation on how to use **GSON** [github URL](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/HURL/src/com/commonsware/android/hurl)

Here are some quick guide lines:

1. Your **Adapter,AsyncTask, Acitvity** classes should be divided into different packages for example : util.asynctasks; and util.adapters; somename.activities; . It's easier to maintain and debug;
2. Keep a code convention. Since you are programming in Java use this guideline:
   https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html
3. When you extend a class like Activity or AsyncTask that you didn't build it's nice to name that class **WhateverExtendingClassName** for example : YourAcitivity. So you know exactly what's its purpose.

Well you don't want to use GSON I personally think that is sad :(.

The code below hopefully will work for you, some things to keep in mind:

1. I copied your code, I changed some of the variable names and I added some code.
2. I have commented where I made changes or added code.
3. I use the **notifyDataSetChanged()** adapters method in the onPostExecute() **AsyncTask** method, you should try using the notifyItemInserted(int)
   notifyItemRemoved(int) method's to add and remove items based on what you recieved from your API.

Below is the code for your Activity and AsyncTask:

```
public class OrderCoffee extends Activity {

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<ShopInfo> shopInfoList; //I changed this
private static String url_all_products = "xxxxxxxxxx/ordercoffee.php";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray shops = null;


// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SHOPS = "shops";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";


//get a list of participating coffee shops in the locality that are using the app
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_coffee);
    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    shopInfoList = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();//I changed this
    ShopAdapter shopAdapter = new ShopAdapter(ShopInfoList);//I changed this
    recList.setAdapter(shopAdapter);//I changed this

    LoadAllProducts loadAllProducts = new LoadAllProducts(shopAdapter)//I added this
    loadAllProducts.execute();//I changed this
}


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ShopAdapter shopAdapter;//I added this
    ArrayList<ShopInfo> shopInfoList = new ArrayList<ShopInfo>();//I added this

    public LoadAllProducts(ShopAdapter shopAdapter)//I added this
    {
        this.shopAdapter = shopAdapter;//I added this
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) //I changed this{
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array
                shops = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOPS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < shops.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = shops.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    ShopInfo shopInfo = new ShopInfo();//I changed this
                    shopInfo.setId(id);//I changed this
                    shopInfo.setName(name);//I changed this

                    shopInfoList.add(shopInfo);//I changed this
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result)//I added this{
      shopAdapter.setShopList(shopInfoList); //I added this
      shopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   //I added this
   }
}
```

And the Adapter code:

```
public class ShopAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopAdapter.ShopViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ShopInfo> shopList;//I added this

    public ShopAdapter(ArrayList<ShopInfo> shopList)//I added this {
        this.shopList = shopList;//I added this
    }

    public void setShopList(ArrayList<ShopInfo> shopList)
    {
         this.shopList = shopList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shopList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShopViewHolder shopViewHolder, int i) {
        ShopInfo ci = shopList.get(i);
        shopViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
        shopViewHolder.vAddress.setText(ci.address);

    }

    @Override
    public ShopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new ShopViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class ShopViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView vName;
        protected TextView vAddress;


        public ShopViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            vAddress = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.address);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I've done a lot of this project with JSON and I want to keep it consistent. Though next time I will have to look at GSON as my method. How do I update recyclerView in the onPostExecute method?

Comment: If I could accept two answers I would. I will take your feedback on GSON for my next project for sure, I just started off with JSON so thought I would stick to it.

Comment: Bravo Arlind for deep explanation!