# Trying to parse JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

How would you suggest me to parse this JSON:

```
{"17": {"user_name": "test1"}, "18": {"user_name": "test5"}, "19": {"user_name": "test9"}}
```

I need to get "username",but i cant find the way to do it. Maybe i should change JSON to something like that:

```
[{"user_name": "test1"},{"user_name": "test5"},{"user_name": "test9"}]
```

This way i tried to get "user_name"s:

```
try {
        List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str = "[{"user_name": "test1"},{"user_name": "test5"},{"user_name": "test9"}]";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);

            for ( int i = 0; i < json.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject actor = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String user_name = actor.getString("user_name");
                allNames.add(user_name);
            }

} catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But then i get Problem with that line:

```
JSONObject actor = json.getJSONObject(i);
```

Android studio tells me that JSONObject cannot be applied to int(i). I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Can somebody please give me some hint, tutorial or an example?

Much appreciated !

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571680/putting-json-data-into-a-list/29572036#29572036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`JSONObject.getJSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) requires a `String` argument (the name or key of the object), not an `int`. In your case, the keys are `"17"`, `"18"` and `"19"`. To get all keys, use the [`JSONObject.keys()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) method:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
Iterator<String> keyIterator = json.keys();
while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
  JSONObject actor = json.getJSONObject(keyIterator.next());
  String user_name = actor.getString("user_name");
  allNames.add(user_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android studio tells me that JSONObject cannot be applied to int(i)

Because `JSONObject.getJSONObject` method takes key name as `String` instead of `int`. and keys in posted json is `17,18,...` to access inner `JSONObject`.

To get all `user_name` from JSONObject,need to get all keys:

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   String key = iter.next();
   JSONObject actor = json.getJSONObject(key);
   String user_name = actor.getString("user_name");
   allNames.add(user_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
try {
    List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str = "[{"user_name": "test1"},{"user_name": "test5"},{"user_name": "test9"}]";

    JSONOArray jsonArray = new JSONOArray(str);

        for ( int i = 0; i < jsonArray .length() ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject actor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String user_name = actor.getString("user_name");
            allNames.add(user_name);
        }

} catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = {"17": {"user_name": "test1"}, "18": {"user_name": "test5"}, "19": {"user_name": "test9"}}
JSONObject ob1 = new JSONObject(str)
JSONObject ob2 = ob1.getJSONObject("17");
String userName = ob2.getString("user_name");


str = [{"user_name": "test1"},{"user_name": "test5"},{"user_name": "test9"}]
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("str");
for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject ob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    allNames.add(ob.getString("user_name")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the Gson library it's very easy.

```
    String json = "{\"17\": {\"user_name\": \"test1\"}, \"18\": {\"user_name\": \"test5\"}, \"19\": {\"user_name\": \"test9\"}}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Map<String,User> users = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String,User> >(){}.getType());
    for(String key : users.keySet()) {
        Log.d("DEBUG",key+" -> "+users.get(key).getUser_name());
    }
```

The User class is a simple POJO like:

public class User {

```
private String user_name;

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to parse `JSONArray` into `JSONObject` at

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
```

use the below code.....

```
try {
        List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str = "[{"user_name": "test1"},{"user_name": "test5"},{"user_name": "test9"}]";
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(str);

            for ( int i = 0; i < json.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject actor = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String user_name = actor.getString("user_name");
                allNames.add(user_name);
            }

} catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block`enter code here`
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```